# Suspend auto-layout while view is hidden

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

Is there a way to suspend the evaluation of a `UIView`'s layout constraints (i.e. stop laying out its subviews) while that view is hidden?

In general, is there a way to pause and resume auto-layout without removing and adding back constraints?